# user accessible in template without passing to context

Tags: python, django

i have the following code.

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def ListDeleteNoteView(request, pk):
    query_note = Note.objects.filter(id=pk).get()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query_note.delete()
        return redirect('dashboard')
    context = {
        'note': query_note
    }
    return render(request, 'notes/note.html', context)
```

in the template,am able to access  `{{user}}`. i dont understand why am able to do soo. i never passed it to context.why is this soo guys??. It also didnt come from the inherited base.html

Comment: Also,how can i place a global authentication rather than using login_required decorator??

Comment: It's because you probably have Django's default context processors enabled, [one of which](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) adds `user` to the context.